# Node.js export properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

What am I doing wrong? Result of module method getFile is always undefined.

Here is code (routing):

```
let router = { 
paths : {
    'rest' : 'rest.info',
    'data' : 'data-info'
},

getFile : (url) => {
   console.log(this.paths);
}
};

module.exports = {
    router : router
}
```

Here is code from simple server:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const router = require('./routing');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
router.getFile('rest');
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
fs.createReadStream('./views/myview.html').pipe(res);

}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: It is `module.exports`

Answer (score 1):

Try `const router = require('./routing').router`

Because the module.exports is an object with `router` as a property

This can also be accomplished through destructuring using a suitable node version:

```
const { router } = require('./routing');
```

Comment: this.paths is still undefined and I am really not sure why.

Comment: From inside the object router.paths wont work. If I console.log(this) I get empty object {}.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to pluralize `export` like so:

`module.exports = {..`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Type error only here on stack, but yes it should be exports.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access `this.paths` change your **getFile** method like this:

```
getFile(url) {
   console.log(this.paths);
}
```